# postgresql max_connections

Tags: postgresql

Что подразумевается в документации по postgresql для  max_connections - "Определяет максимальное число одновременных подключений к серверу БД"?

Имеется ввиду количество пользователей, например:

1. У меня есть 1 БД и 2 сервера которые ее дергают "1 база 2 юзера".
   или
2. У меня есть 1 БД, 1 сервер и 100 подключенных клиентов "1 база 1 юзер 100 подключений".

Какой из этих вариантов верный и если первый вариант, то сколько за раз по дефолту postgresql может поддержать подключенных клиентов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max_connections` - именно максимальное количество одновременных клиентских подключений. (строго говоря зависит от версии базы, например `wal sender` процессы репликации до 12 версии тоже считались как клиентская сессия)

Пользователи, базы данных, сервера - неважно. Важно количество подключений к этому инстансу postgresql. Подключились через psql - заняли слот подключения. Открыли в приложении коннект к базе - заняли слот. Сделали в приложении пул соединений с настройками на постоянное поддержание 10 соединений с базой - заняли 10 соединений. Два разных пользователя через psql подключились к разным базам одного экземпляра postgresql - заняли два слота подключений. И так далее.

> сколько за раз по дефолту postgresql может поддержать подключенных клиентов?

Обычный дефолт 100 подключений. Во время выполнения начальной установки `initdb` [может выбрать](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_12_STABLE/src/bin/initdb/initdb.c#L987) меньшее число соединений в качестве значения по умолчанию. Впрочем, не представляю где надо запускать базу (сейчас, а не 25 лет назад) чтобы это потребовалось.

### Не надо задирать max_connections в небеса

Это не бесплатная штука. Каждое соединение - это отдельный процесс операционной системы, порождаемый вызовом `fork` при подключении к базе и завершающийся при отключении клиента. Частые открытия/закрытия соединений для процессной модели postgresql вообще противопоказаны, будете тратить systime cpu вместо реальной работы. Далее, каждый процесс хранит собственный кэш системного каталога, хранимых процедур, prepared statements, буфер временных таблиц и разное прочее полезное. Отсюда проистекает любопытный фокус, который может быть даже заметен на практике - первый запрос в сессии медленнее последующих.

И даже каждое неиспользуемое соединение увеличивает размеры структур в сегменте разделяемой памяти (именно из-за этих структур max_connections может быть задан только при старте СУБД), а, следовательно, и накладные расходы по управлению этим хозяйством.

Основное счастье, конечно, когда прилетает через сотню соединений сотня конкурентных запросов, а у вас оказывается было всего с 8 ядер CPU. Планировщик операционной системы пытается дать поработать всем процессам, попутно мешая каждому из них. Даже без специальных приключений оказывается, что такое все-мешают-всем по итоговым затратам времени оказывается дольше, чем если бы часть из них даже постояла в очереди и выполнилась чуть позже. А потом ещё окажется что один процесс держал легковесную блокировку после spinlock и на самом деле все ждали его (так же в своих spinlock), а тому времени CPU собственно и не доставалось чтобы сделать что надо было и отпустить уже блокировку...

С точки зрения администрирования PostgreSQL наиболее выигрышная ситуация при малом числе процессов, но хорошо загруженных потоком выполнения запросов. Гораздо хуже если открыто множество соединений, но они постоянно в состоянии простоя (`idle`). Худший сценарий - постоянно открывать и закрывать соединения. Очень редко где основное приложение (не разработчики и другие интересующиеся, особенно через GUI) обращается к базе напрямую, а не через [`pgbouncer`](http://www.pgbouncer.org/) в режиме пула транзакций. Этот режим накладывает свои ограничения на использование некоторых сессионных возможностей, зато эффективно уменьшает число используемых соединений базы.